# Is changing a variable in a recursive call considered mutation

Tags: python, recursion, sum, mutable, mutation

My goal is to sum a list without using mutation.

```
def noMutObj(lst,pointer=0, result=0):
    if pointer == len(lst): 
        return result
    newResult = result + lst[pointer]
    return noMutObj(lst, pointer+1, newResult)
```

Would we consider `pointer` mutating as we take a step into the recursion, 
*or* does mutation apply only to a variable changing in a iterative loop?

Comment: Do the values in `lst` change? No? Then there is no mutation.

Comment: (...and to be clear, that doesn't mean "the values bound to the name `lst`", but rather, "the values within a single instance of `lst`"; you can bind a different list instance to the same name, but if you don't change the contents of a single instance, there's no mutation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mutated `pointer`: you've passed a *different* value into each call to `noMutObj`.  Each stack frame has its own `pointer`, none of which are changed.  Even then, you would be changing only your local copy.

You *would* have mutation if you did something such as

```
lst.append(newResult)
return noMutObj(lst, pointer+1, newResult)
```

Before the call.  Instead, the proper way to send an altered list to the next call would be something such as

```
return noMutObj(lst[:].append(newResult), pointer+1, newResult)
```

... which creates a new list, appends `newResult` and passes that temporary object to the next level.

I know this is not at all what you intended your function to do; I'm merely illustrating the syntactic and semantic principles.

**UPDATE**

Ah ... now that we have a purpose ...

Mutation:

```
def noMutObj(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0: 
        return 0
    return lst.pop() + noMutObj(lst)
```

No mutation:

```
def noMutObj(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0: 
        return 0
    return lst[0] + noMutObj(lst[1:])
```